# MySQL combine two tables by id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

Table **alpha**

```
id  |  title  |  catid

1   |  winter |  105
2   |  summer |  105
3   |  fall   |  20
4   |  spring |  12
```

Table **beta**

```
id  |  author

1   |  john
2   |  mike
3   |  bill
```

Table **result** — I would like to generate the following table by matching the id from the two tables above. Using only those colums WHERE "catdid" is 105.

```
id  |  author |  title

1   |  john   |  winter
2   |  mike   |  summer
```

I have the following query:

```
$table_alpha = "alpha";
$table_beta = "beta";

$sql = "
SELECT id, title, catid, author 
FROM $table_alpha, $table_beta 
WHERE catid = 105
…
???
…
";
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this on my phone, so I hope it works, but you really just need to use a `JOIN`.

```
$table_alpha = "alpha";
$table_beta  = "beta";

$sql = "
    SELECT id, title, catid, author
    FROM $table_alpha
    JOIN $table_beta USING(id) 
    WHERE catid = 105
";
```

The `USING` clause tells the query to treat `id` the thing to join on. That should make it safe to query for it by name without stating which `id` to retrieve (man I wish I could verify that, but no SQL on my phone :-p)

Comment: awesome. This one works!! They other resulted in "no result".

Comment: Cool, glad it did the job. The `USING` statement is great if the `JOIN` condition is nice and simple, otherwise, keep an eye out for the `ON` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your query was quite close, you need to use a JOIN with a condition:

```
$table_alpha = "alpha";
$table_beta = "beta";

$sql = "
SELECT $table_alpha.id, title, author 
FROM $table_alpha
JOIN $table_beta 
ON $table_alpha.id=$table_beta.id
WHERE catid = 105
"
```

Comment: You might get a `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous` error there. Using a `USING(id)` instead of the `ON` statement *should* do the trick. Or else you could change the `SELECT` to `$table_alpha.id`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT a.id, b.author, a.title
FROM alpha AS a
INNER JOIN beta AS b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.catid = 105;
```

Comment: You need to tell the `JOIN` what condition to join the tables on as well. You can do this with `ON alpha.id = beta.id` or `USING(id)`.

Comment: Ha! Took me a while to realise what you meant. Completely forgot while doing work on the other screen. Thanks for the correction!